# joomla logs/error.php language

Tags: php, joomla, error-logging

I have a website running joomla. The site is in German language, and the log entries(wrong password etc.) are mostly in German too, but some recently failed attempts to login are logged in english.
Can someone explain what criteria is used to determine in what language the logs/error.php is writen?

edit:the log entries:

```
Joomla FAILURE:     Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.
Joomla FAILURE:     Benutzername und Passwort falsch oder das Benutzerkonto existiert noch nicht!
```

Comment: Share more details with us to get help. E.g. you could post these log messages in your original post.

Comment: edited the post, in the second line is the german translation of the first line, and the english error was raised by a german ip adress

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked into this, but it seems reasonable that browser language settings which can change the frontend language, also influence language in log-messages? I mean, it would be more logical that log messages used default admin language, but this does not seem to be the case.